# Can't make Shift modifier work with function keys

Tags: autohotkey

I want to map F1-F3 to Copy, Paste and Cut respectively. But if Shift pressed F1-F3 must do what they do by default.

Suppose I have some file clicked, so Shift+F2 have to invoke Rename of this file.

`+F2::F2` doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I also think that by the documentation this should have worked,
but sometimes one needs to test different formulations in AHK
to find one that works.

This formulation is safe and it works :

```
+F2::Send, {F2}
```

Note : I usually use Send for sending keys, as it works in all cases.

Comment: If I comment F2::Send "{LCtrl down}v{LCtrl up}" then it works, but I suppose Shift key in that case doesn't make any difference.